# Adding onLoaded handler for Silverlight via HTML

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I am not a pro in Silverlight 2.0, but for those who are, is it possible to add an event handler for the Silverlight host via javascript in an HTML file. In short, is it possible to add parameters to the object tags like these

```
<param name="onLoaded" value="myjavascripthanderforloaded" />
<param name="onMouseEnter" value="myjavascipthandlerformouse" />
```

I need to add some XAML content into this Silverlight app via my javascript.
I do not have access to the XAML code, I just have the compiled XAP with me.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of late but I hope it still helps you.

I was able to add the handler by creating the Silverlight objet dynamically with the Javascript.js file take a look at the following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265155%28v=vs.95%29

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you could register any events from outside the silverlight plugin (if it's that what you want and if I understand you right...).
But you can pass parameters...
Read more here...

http://jesseliberty.com/2008/12/26/passing-parameters-into-silverlight-applications/

http://blogger.forgottenskies.com/?p=112